# How to bind onchange event to a particular row's element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting the data for all users, displayed that data in table. I was able to get the particular row's user-id, now I am trying to add onchange event for that particular row's element. When I click on edit button all input fields are taking values but all values are changing under that category. e.g. If I click on edit and start typing name, all fields inside name column are changing. I only want to change that particular field on respective row

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getAllDash, updateAdminUser } from "../fetchingData/api_calls";
import "./profile.css";
import { Table } from "reactstrap";

class AdminDash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: [],
      edit: false,
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      error: false,
      verification: false,
      role: "user",
      input: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    getAllDash(token).then((data) => {
      data.map((user_id, idx) => {
        this.setState({
          users: data,
        });
      });
    });
  }
  editbtn = (id) => {
    console.log("id is..", id);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      // edit: !this.state.edit,
      users: state.users.map((csid) => {
        if (csid.user_id === id.user_id) {
          console.log(id.user_id);
          return {
            ...csid,
            edit: !state.edit,
            log: console.log("state is if", !state.edit),
            // edit: this.state.edit,
          };
        } else {
          console.log("state is else", this.state.edit);
          return csid;
        }
      }),
      edit: !this.state.edit,
      // log: console.log("state is edit", !this.state.edit),
      // edit:state.edit
    }));
    this.editbtn = this.editbtn.bind(this);
  };
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.users.map((data, index) => {
      const {
        user_id,
        user_firstname,
        user_lastname,
        user_phone,
        user_email,
        user_role,
        user_verification,
      } = data; //destructuring

      return (
        <tr key={user_id}>
          <td> {++index}</td>
          <td> {user_id}</td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              value={this.state.firstname}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })}}
              placeholder={user_firstname}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              value={this.state.lastname}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_lastname}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_email}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
            value={this.state.role}
            // onChange={(e) => this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_role}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              value={this.state.phone}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_phone}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              value={this.state.verification}
              placeholder={user_verification}
              disabled={!this.state.edit}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={(e) => this.editbtn(data, e)} key={data.user_id}>
              {this.state.edit ? "Cancel" : "edit"}
            </button>
            <button>Save changes</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="adminDash">
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th id="number">No.</th>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>User First Name</th>
              <th>User Last Name</th>
              <th>User Email</th>
              <th>User Role</th>
              <th>User Phone</th>
              <th>user verification</th>
              <th>User status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.renderTableData()}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminDash;
```

Comment: You've one single `editbtn` state that ***every*** row references, and also the one single set of row field values that ***every*** input uses as `value` prop. I don't think you've need of the field state, the mapped rows' inputs' `value` should be the row data, not state.

Comment: Actually i am using state, so that with post request i can push the edited data to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

In addition to the single `edit` state being used by every input in every row, when you are in edit mode each input is using the same state to provide their `value` prop.

The main issue is that the mapped row data isn't really being used.

## Solution

1. Update `editbtn` callback to simply toggle the edit mode. Instead of toggling a boolean value though, toggle between `null` and a user's `user_id` so you can match a row to edit.

   ```
   editbtn = (data) => {
     const {
       user_id
     } = data;

     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       edit: prevState.edit === user_id ? null : user_id
     }));
   };
   ```
2. Implement `componentDidUpdate` to populate or reset the field state values based upon the current `edit` state value. If `edit` is truthy then search for a user in the `users` array and if found, populate state, otherwise reset the field state values.

   ```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if (prevState.edit !== this.state.edit) {
       if (this.state.edit) {
         const user = this.state.users.find(
           (user) => user.user_id === this.state.edit
         );

         if (user) {
           this.setState({
             firstname: user.user_firstname,
             lastname: user.user_lastname,
             phone: user.user_phone,
             email: user.user_email,
             verification: user.user_verification,
             role: user.user_role
           });
         }
       } else {
         this.setState((prevState) => ({
           firstname: "",
           lastname: "",
           phone: "",
           email: "",
           verification: false,
           role: "user"
         }));
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Compute an `isEditable` value to pass to the `disabled` attribute of the inputs.
4. Additionally, if a specific user/row is editable, conditionally pass either the user data value, or the field state that is storing the edited value

   ```
   renderTableData() {
     return this.state.users.map((data, index) => {
       const {
         user_id,
         user_firstname,
         ...
       } = data; //destructuring

       const isEditable = this.state.edit === user_id;

       return (
         <tr key={user_id}>
           <td> {index + 1}</td>
           <td> {user_id}</td>
           <td>
             <input
               value={isEditable ? this.state.firstname : user_firstname}
               onChange={(e) => {
                 this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value });
               }}
               placeholder={user_firstname}
               disabled={!isEditable}
             />
           </td>
           ...
   ```
5. For completion's sake, implement the "save data" button's callback. This will take the field state data and update the user record in the `users` array in state. This also clears the field input state values and resets the `edit` back to `null` to take the row out of edit mode.

   ```
   saveData = () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       users: prevState.users.map((user) =>
         user.user_id === prevState.edit
           ? {
               ...user,
               user_firstname: prevState.firstname,
               user_lastname: prevState.lastname,
               user_phone: prevState.phone,
               user_email: prevState.email,
               user_role: prevState.role,
               user_verification: prevState.verification
             }
           : user
       ),
       edit: null,
       firstname: "",
       lastname: "",
       phone: "",
       email: "",
       verification: false,
       role: "user"
     }));
   };
   ```
6. Minor issue in `componentDidMount`. you loop over your `data` array and enqueue a bunch of state updates that just enqueue the same update. There's no need for a `data.map` here, a single `this.setState({ users: data });` should suffice.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
     getAllDash(token).then((data) => {
       this.setState({ users: data });
     });
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-bind-onchange-event-to-a-particular-rows-element]

Full sandbox code:

```
class AdminDash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: [],
      edit: null,
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      error: false,
      verification: false,
      role: "user",
      input: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ users: data });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.edit !== this.state.edit) {
      if (this.state.edit) {
        const user = this.state.users.find(
          (user) => user.user_id === this.state.edit
        );

        if (user) {
          this.setState({
            firstname: user.user_firstname,
            lastname: user.user_lastname,
            phone: user.user_phone,
            email: user.user_email,
            verification: user.user_verification,
            role: user.user_role
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          firstname: "",
          lastname: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
          verification: false,
          role: "user"
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  editbtn = (data) => {
    console.log("data is..", data);

    const { user_id } = data;

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      edit: prevState.edit === user_id ? null : user_id
    }));
  };

  saveData = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      users: prevState.users.map((user) =>
        user.user_id === prevState.edit
          ? {
              ...user,
              user_firstname: prevState.firstname,
              user_lastname: prevState.lastname,
              user_phone: prevState.phone,
              user_email: prevState.email,
              user_role: prevState.role,
              user_verification: prevState.verification
            }
          : user
      ),
      edit: null,
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      verification: false,
      role: "user"
    }));
  };

  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.users.map((data, index) => {
      const {
        user_id,
        user_firstname,
        user_lastname,
        user_phone,
        user_email,
        user_role,
        user_verification
      } = data; //destructuring

      const isEditable = this.state.edit === user_id;

      return (
        <tr key={user_id}>
          <td> {index + 1}</td>
          <td> {user_id}</td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.firstname : user_firstname}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value });
              }}
              placeholder={user_firstname}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.lastname : user_lastname}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_lastname}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.email : user_email}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_email}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.role : user_role}
              // onChange={(e) => this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_role}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.phone : user_phone}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
              placeholder={user_phone}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              value={isEditable ? this.state.verification : user_verification}
              placeholder={user_verification}
              disabled={!isEditable}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={() => this.editbtn(data)}>
              {isEditable ? "Cancel" : "edit"}
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.saveData}>Save changes</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="adminDash">
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th id="number">No.</th>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>User First Name</th>
              <th>User Last Name</th>
              <th>User Email</th>
              <th>User Role</th>
              <th>User Phone</th>
              <th>user verification</th>
              <th>User status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.renderTableData()}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```